# Developing an image frame sequence generator in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, feature-detection, sequence-generators

I am doing a project where I have to create frames of images, to show a track path of an object and detect it. The end goal of my code is to create a line that shows the track path of the object as it moves and a box to detect the object at it's final position on the image (original image and desired output image that I would like is shown as an example).

In order to do this, I need help with generating the frames with different object positions. I have already created an object from an array (using the zeros function) with a set intensity value and have overlayed it on to the original background image (using imadd(image, object)). I have different frames with the object at different positions. Any idea, how I can show a streak/line to show the track path of the object?

I would really appreciate any help with this.

Kind regards,

Vanessa

P.S. This is the how original data looks like:

[image: Original frame][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq8tI.png)]

And this is the desired output:

[image: Desired final output]